# The role of mangle table in nfqueue

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am trying to access and change packets contents programmatically over Ubuntu using `nfqueue` C program in conjunction with `iptables` rules in order to alter packets in the queue over eth0 (to the out world) and eth1 (to the inner LAN). I had to use *masquerade* for source NATing and `mangle` for packet alteration. Now I have noticed that the side which initiates the ping request or TCP executes the *masquerade* rule just right (this is correct for both sides). But the reply packets and TCP ACK does not apply *masquerade* rule and the packets exit with the internal LAN IP (192.168.x.x). Also this is happening at both sides.

Q1. What must I do to control these reply packets?

Q2. As the reply and TCP ACK packets arrive to the other side on the Internet with the LAN source IP. Is it allowed over the Internet that the source IP could be a private IP (192.168.x.x)? N.b. All of the above is applied also over the source port in which I do changes, but does not respond in reply or TCP ACK. While changing payloads or `dst`. IP is applied correctly.